# Взять во временную таблицу результат выполнения хранимой процедуры

Tags: sql, sql-server

Используем SQL Server 2012. 
Имеется хранимая процедура такого вида которая содержит два выражения с SELECT. Менять ее нельзя.

```
create procedure name 
begin 
  select * from table1
  select * from table2
end
```

Мне нужно вызвать данную процедуру и сохранить во временные таблицы результаты этих селектов. Примерно так:

```
CREATE TABLE results_1(params)
CREATE TABLE results_2(params)
insert into results_1 /*select dataset1 from exec name*/
insert into results_2 /*select dataset2 from exec name*/
```

Comment: чтобы сохранить данные из процедуры Вам нужно создать таблицу вне этой процедуры. Как вариант, в процедуре в каждый из селектов добавляете какой-то идентификатор таблицы, затем данные из временной таблицы разделяете в 2 разных таблицы.

Comment: Если у таблиц tabe1 и table2 одинаковая структура, то ещё можно поплясать(результат обоих запросов запишется в одну таблицу INSERT INTO results EXEC name) - если нет, то на стороне SQL сервера это невозможно, насколько мне известно. Несколько резалтсетов разной структуры можно разобрать только на клиенте.

Comment: Ко второму набору обратиться средствами SQL не получится, не важно одинаковая структура таблиц или нет

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/da5328a7-5dab-44b3-b2b1-4a8d6d7798b2/insert-into-table-one-or-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql здесь возможный вариант решения (англ.)

Comment: Видимо, необходимую мне логику придется писать в коде. Всем спасибо.